# Problem when I try to delete data and files

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new in Laravel, and I'm doing a project for my university, and I've two problems when I try to delete:

**First error:** When I try to delete the records, only the first one (with ID 1) doesn't delete from the table, but the other if deleted from the table and I've already tried some things to fix the error, but I couldn't:

Controller.php:

```php
public function destroy_int($inst_id)
    {
        $inst = InstitucionEntidadInt::where('id', $inst_id);
        $inst->delete();
        return redirect('/activities/cons_instituciones_int');
    }
```

Web.php:

```php
Route::delete('/delete_inst_int/{inst_id}', [InstEntController::class, 'destroy_int'])
    ->name('institucion_int.destroy');
```

**Second error:** In some forms, it's necessary to upload and save files in a database (so I save just the name in the database and the files are saved in the public path). And some of this input files are multiple, so I save the names in the database like a JSON (using the json_encode method):

```php
//This is the way that I save the files
$files = [];

if ($request->hasFile('inst_docsoporteNac')) {
    foreach ($request->file('inst_docsoporteNac') as $file) {
        $name = time() . "_" . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path('files/institucionesNac'), $name);
        $files[] = $name;
    }
}

$instentNact->docSoportes = json_encode($files);
```

So, I'm trying to implement the delete method and I need to delete the files from both places (from the DB and the public path), I don't know how I can do it and I've already tried some "solutions" that I read from some forums (like this).

Controller.php:

```php
public function destroy_nac($inst_id)
    {

        $inst = InstEntNac::where('id', $inst_id);
        $files = InstEntNac::where('id', $inst_id)->get('docSoportes');
        foreach (json_decode($files) as $file) {
            Storage::delete(public_path('files/institucionesNac/' . $file));
        }
        $inst->delete();
        return redirect('/activities/cons_instituciones_nac');
    }
```

This is the way that I'm using, but I'm getting an error **"Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"**.

I'll appreciate your solutions for these errors.

Comment: Why json_decode $files before deleting?

Comment: 'Cause I need to access the name saved in the DB and using it to delete from the public path (and are multiples files/names), "I guess".

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, you can add error handling using this code:

```
InstitucionEntidadInt::findOrFail($inst_id)->delete();
```

For the second error, json_decode returns by default stdClass object instead of array. You can tell the function to return array type with second boolean parameter setting it to true:

```
json_decode($files, true)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the first solution didn't work, it's still not deleting the record with ID 1.

And the second solution I'm getting other error "Array to string conversion".

Comment: Actually, I don't know why are you using json_decode here.

Comment: You'd better do it like this: InstEntNac::where('id', $inst_id)->get('docSoportes')->each(function(InstEntNac $file) { Storage::delete(public_path('files/institucionesNac/' . $file->docSoportes));});

Comment: Regarding id 1, it should work. Make sure that id slug is passed correctly to the route. Do you get an error here or just nothing happens?

Comment: Trying your solution for the file didn't work, I don't get an error but nothing appends.  
And nothing happens with the record ID 1, I try with dd() method and I get nothing, but it's curious because with the others I use that method and I get something (the ID). With that is like just refresh the page and nothing else.

Comment: I found the problem, when I get the files' name saved in the DB and I see its types, they are "string" and not an "array". So, when I wanna delete it, nothing happens for this reason. But it's strange because when I show each name in the view, I use a foreach, and it works, and I apply a download method for each file and I don't know why I can fix this.